# Why am I getting mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory when trying to login to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am new to PHP and MySQL and backend programming as a whole and am trying to get a live server setup with phpMyAdmin and MySQL.

I've followed instructions from a YouTube video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHYh-m4iXw4&t=608s) but can't seem to actually login to phpMyAdmin after having copied the config file into the phpMyAdmin directory.

When I'm in the setup for phpMyAdmin I see that I also have this error:

> Zip decompression requires functions (zip_open) which are unavailable on this system.

Not sure if this is related to why I am not able to log in.

I am using mysql version 8.0.20 on Mac 0S

Comment: "no such file or directory" means the mysql socket you are connecting to doesn't exist. Check the mysql service is started. Also check where it creates its socket. `zip_open` is an unrelated error probably needs some zip library installed. Details used from YouTube video (which?), operating system, distribution version, mysql version and even phpmyadmin version are some of the useful things that would be good to include with such a question.